# isDisplayed() passes before table containing element appears on webpage

Tags: selenium, webdriver

I have been noticing that when I use the `isDisplayed()` to check if an element `id` is visible, the test passes, even though the `table` element is in, has not finished rendering on the web page. The `table` has not appeared and `isDisplayed()` is already passing for the element id within it.

Is it because the element id already exists in the DOM ? I thought `isDisplayed()` will cover `isVisible()` or am I totally wrong ? Is there any other webdriver method or WebElement method I could use to make sure this test is working right ?

Comment: Check this
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18062372/how-does-selenium-webdrivers-isdisplayed-method-work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18062372/how-does-selenium-webdrivers-isdisplayed-method-work)

Comment: Maybe the element is visible, but it hasn't yet been populated by some Ajax.  I like tomasz.myszka's link.