# Button is not visible and returning TRUE, button xpath is in web page,for selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

Using selenium webdriver to  test if the button is not visible the boolean is always returning true.

using below code and returns TRUE,in web page I can see the xpath for Add button. Button is not visible.

```
    boolean present;  
    try { 
        //driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@id='add']")); 
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@id='add']")).isDisplayed();
       present = true;
       System.out.println("Add button is present");   
    } catch (NoSuchElementException e) { 
       present = false;
       System.out.println("Add button is not present:" +e.getMessage()); 
}
```

xpath:
[addButtonxpath](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LGFyt.png)

Answer (score 0):

This is correct behaviour

`driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@id='add']")).isDisplayed();` this will return as false however you have explicitly define `present = true;` in next line.

What you could do use if..else block

```
        boolean present;  
        if (driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@id='add']")).isDisplayed())
        {
            present=true;
            System.out.println("Add button is present");  
        }
        else
        {
            present = false;
            System.out.println("Add button is Not present");  
        }
```

Comment: Output is still: add button is present .  Button itself not in the web page

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code snippet

```
boolean present;
try {
    present = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@id='add']")).isDisplayed();
    System.out.println("Add button is present");
} catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
    present = false;
    System.out.println("Add button is not present:" + e.getMessage());
} catch (Exception e) {
    present = false;
    System.out.println("Add button is not present:" + e.getMessage());
}
```

Comment: still getting Add button is present

Comment: May be element present in the DOM, Is there more than one Add button present in the DOM, you could check for the visibility: visible; attribute, get the visibility attribute value and check if its hidden

Comment: Only one button and I checked the element its not tagged as hidden

Answer (score 0):

[Working of `isDisplayed()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18062372/how-does-selenium-webdrivers-isdisplayed-method-work/18078554) method is doubtful and topic of debate. Having said that in your case `isDisplayed()` is not working because it is getting element in the DOM and returning true even though the element is not visible on the UI.

There is style attribute in the DOM for this button by checking that you can be on the conclusion. Like -

`driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@id='add' and @style='display:none;']")`

Now enable the button and check the style property, It will be changed to something else use that value and create xpath using that. and Check for add button elements presence. Then your `isDisplayed()` method may work as intended.

Comment: Thank you! it worked when i gave the xpath as "//button[@id='add' and @style='display:none;']"